# Is it possible to use the 'unity-greeter' for LightDM on Xubuntu 11.10?

Tags: login-screen, xubuntu, lightdm

I was wondering if there is a way to use the 'unity-greeter' instead of 'lightdm-gtk-greeter' for LightDM on Xubuntu Oneiric. I tried installing the unity-greeter package and changing the greeter-session entry in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf, but when I restart the system I get a blinking screen and the boot process get stuck.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for this.. it may work.

In my case, I installed Xubuntu 11.10 - which came with LightDM using the gtk greeter. I edited `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` to use unity-greeter (after installing it, of course) and had the same issue.

In my case, I fixed it by installing gnome-settings-daemon from Synaptic. Seems it might be required by Unity Greeter, but isn't a dependency.

See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/850937

Hope it helps

Comment: That solved the problem almost perfectly. The only issue left is that the unity-greeter seems to be coded to use the Ubuntu indicators in order to display the hour, battery state and the shutdown menu, but I don't want to install them because all the dependencies. By the way, is good to know the bug is reported already.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this should work.  Please have a look at `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log` to see why LightDM is failing to start Unity Greeter.

Comment: i have the same issue. and syslog says that : kernel: [   18.799858] unity-greeter[1227]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f3ea4943b70 sp 00007fff665335e8 error 4 in libgio-2.0.so.0.3000.0[7f3ea48aa000+13b000]