# Can't switch between lightdm and gdm

Tags: lightdm, gdm, ubuntu-studio

I installed Ubuntu Studio 13.10 from a minimal CD, and then upgraded to 14.04. But since the cd install, I have been trying to change from gdm to lightdm. I have tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`, `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`, reinstalling lightdm, but none of this works for me. Any idea?

Thank you!

**Edit**

I am not allowed to post an answer right now, so here it is if someone needs it before I can write a real one.

*Ok, I found the answer on this thread: [Is it possible to use the 'unity-greeter' for LightDM on Xubuntu 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68234/is-it-possible-to-use-the-unity-greeter-for-lightdm-on-xubuntu-11-10)
Turns out lightDM was activated, but the interface looked different. The greeter I had was called `lightdm-gtk-greeter` and the one I was used to `unity-greeter`. So all I had to do was to change the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`*

Comment: Oh, well done for getting there though :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you rebooted? Also try

```
sudo gdm stop
sudo lightdm stop
sudo lightdm start
```

Or

```
sudo service gdm stop
sudo service lightdm start
```

Sources: 
Own knowledge 
Inverse of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151334/how-do-i-make-gdm-the-default-display-manager)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, the first three make my screen look all jittery and unusable (sorry if this is a bit unclear); and the other two do not work, ubuntu has a problem with the keyword `stop`